# Confused about how to connect sqlserver via JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

This is my first java application I have been  trying to connect to sql and get some  records for three hours.I dont get any execptions or errors.but nothing displayed so far.I am not sure if am i connected or not

```
           public static  void main(String[]args) throws ClassNotFoundException 
           ,SQLException{


  String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://.\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Northwind; Integrated   Security=SSPI";  
         Integrated Security=SSPI";

         Connection con=null;
         Statement stmt=null;

         ResultSet rs=null;
         try {
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver");

             con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             String sql="Select Top 3 from * person.Contact";
             stmt=con.createStatement();
             rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
             while(rs.next()){
             System.out.println(rs.getString(1));



             }
              }

         catch ( Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

Comment: You can't see exceptions because your are lost them!

Comment: What do you think the line `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver");` is doing?

Comment: a class called Class , fetch the driver for the specified vendor

Comment: And do what with it? The result is being thrown away.

Comment: @pamphlet what is your question ?

Comment: Yes @pamphlet What do you mean?

Comment: My intention is to bring attention to the fact that the `Class.forName`... line appears to serve no purpose.

Comment: You are ignoring the exceptions thrown, most likely it is failing because your URL is invalid: you need to specify a host name (in the URL or in a Properties object), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx

Comment: @pamphlet: it does serve a purpose: it forces the driver to register with the `DriverManager` when the driver class is loaded. With newer drivers that use Java's service registry this would not be necessary though (but it has been necessary until Java 5, check the JDBC tutorials)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I see. How gross. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try displaying the stacktrace

```
try {
  ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: After adding try cath block .I have realized that its ClassNotFoundExecption.then I have followed theese steps

Right-click Project->Select Properties->On the left-hand side click Libraries->Under Compile tab - click Add Jar/Folder button->added both sqljdbc and sqljdbc4 .jar files

But unfortunately same exception again.

Comment: @user2708377 You should add only one of those: Java 5 or older: sqljdbc.jar, Java 6 or newer: sqljdbc4.jar

Answer (score 0):

you can figure out your issue by throwing `exception` or by Exception handling by `try catch`

```
public static  void main(String[]args)throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException
```

or by `stackTrace()`

```
 catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`forName()` throws `ClassNotFoundException`
and `getConnection()` throws `SQLException`